# Too Few Parameters : Expected 1 performing while using UPDATE

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update, microsoft365

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub load_data()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Select * from COMM_RRC"
    List21.ColumnHeads = True
    List21.ColumnCount = 12
    List21.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    List21.RowSource = sql
End Sub

Private Sub Command16_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into COMM_RRC(ID_NO,DATEIST,INBOUND_FLTS,IB_SECTOR,APT,OUTBOUND_FLTS,OB_SECTOR,GUESTS,MAX_DIS_TIME,DISP_ACT,REMARKS_COMM_RRC,NOTE_COMM_RRC,CODE_SHARE_FLTS)" & _
    "Values('" & ID_NO.Value & "','" & DATEIST.Value & "','" & INBOUND_FLTS.Value & "','" & IB_SECTOR.Value & "','" & APT.Value & "','" & OUTBOUND_FLTS.Value & "','" & OB_SECTOR.Value & "','" & GUESTS.Value & "','" & MAX_DIS_TIME.Value & "','" & DISP_ACT.Value & "','" & REMARKS_COMM_RRC.Value & "','" & NOTE_COMM_RRC.Value & "','" & CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value & "')"
    Call load_data
End Sub

Private Sub Command17_Click()
    ID_NO.Value = ""
    DATEIST.Value = ""
    INBOUND_FLTS.Value = ""
    IB_SECTOR.Value = ""
    APT.Value = ""
    OUTBOUND_FLTS.Value = ""
    OB_SECTOR.Value = ""
    GUESTS.Value = ""
    MAX_DIS_TIME.Value = ""
    DISP_ACT.Value = ""
    REMARKS_COMM_RRC.Value = ""
    NOTE_COMM_RRC.Value = ""
    CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Command18_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "Update COMM_RRC Set DATEIST = '" & DATEIST.Value & "',INBOUND_FLTS = '" & INBOUND_FLTS.Value & "',IB_SECTOR = '" & IB_SECTOR.Value & "',APT = '" & APT.Value & "',OUTBOUND_FLTS = '" & OUTBOUND_FLTS.Value & "',OB_SECTOR = '" & OB_SECTOR.Value & "',GUESTS = '" & GUESTS.Value & "',MAX_DIS_TIME = '" & MAX_DIS_TIME.Value & "',DISP_ACT = '" & DISP_ACT.Value & "',REMARKS_COMM_RRC = '" & REMARKS_COMM_RRC.Value & "',NOTE_COMM_RRC = '" & NOTE_COMM_RRC.Value & "',CODE_SHARE_FLTS = " & CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value & " where ID_NO =  '" & ID_NO.Value & " ';"
    Call load_data
End Sub

Private Sub Command19_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "Delete from COMM_RRC Where ID_NO = " & ID_NO.Value & ""
    Call load_data
End Sub

Private Sub Detail_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call load_data
End Sub

Private Sub List21_AfterUpdate()
    ID_NO.Value = List21.Column(0)
    DATEIST.Value = List21.Column(1)
    INBOUND_FLTS.Value = List21.Column(2)
    IB_SECTOR.Value = List21.Column(3)
    APT.Value = List21.Column(4)
    OUTBOUND_FLTS.Value = List21.Column(5)
    OB_SECTOR.Value = List21.Column(6)
    GUESTS.Value = List21.Column(7)
    MAX_DIS_TIME.Value = List21.Column(8)
    DISP_ACT.Value = List21.Column(9)
    REMARKS_COMM_RRC.Value = List21.Column(10)
    NOTE_COMM_RRC.Value = List21.Column(11)
    CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value = List21.Column(12)
End Sub

Private Sub List21_Click()

End Sub
```

I am trying to create a simple data entry form where in operations like Add, New, Update and Delete can be performed. (I am Using Microsoft 365)

Here is the structure of Database [Database structure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld6fi.png) and this one [Database structure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEiGo.png)

But I am getting this error - "Run time error 3061. Too few parameters. Expected 1." [ERROR MSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDMZV.png)

After clicking on Debug ..the editor is pointing towards this block of code -

[Error in Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0kVd.png)

```vb
Private Sub Command18_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "Update COMM_RRC Set DATEIST = '" & DATEIST.Value &
        "',INBOUND_FLTS = '" & INBOUND_FLTS.Value & "',IB_SECTOR = '" &
        IB_SECTOR.Value & "',APT = '" & APT.Value & "',OUTBOUND_FLTS = '" & 
        OUTBOUND_FLTS.Value & "',OB_SECTOR = '" & OB_SECTOR.Value & "',GUESTS = '" &
        GUESTS.Value & "',MAX_DIS_TIME = '" & MAX_DIS_TIME.Value &
        "',DISP_ACT = '" & DISP_ACT.Value & "',REMARKS_COMM_RRC = '" &
        REMARKS_COMM_RRC.Value & "',NOTE_COMM_RRC = '" & NOTE_COMM_RRC.Value &
        "',CODE_SHARE_FLTS = " & CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value & " where ID_NO =  '" &
        ID_NO.Value & " ';"
    Call load_data
End Sub
```

And when i click on END the record gets UPDATED but creates another duplicate copy.

How can stop this error and UPDATE the record.

Comment: What is the code for `CurrentDb.Execute`

Comment: I have already added the code under this line - After clicking on Debug ..the editor is pointing towards this block of code -

Comment: Debug your code. Insert a `Debug.Print "Update ... "` with your whole expression and you will see if it produces valid SQL. You may also try to insert the output in an Access query and look if it runs. You insert a date without formatting it as valid date literal. It should be `#YYYY-MM-DD#`.

Comment: No the actual code for the function called `CurrentDb.Execute`. You have a major SQL injection issue here, but it's unclear if that's what the problem is.

Comment: I am not sure..I am new to this ...Am I missing something?

Comment: @HansUp yes it's inappropriate for the situation because it's a data entry form and it should not create duplicate records while updating...but how can an UPDATE statement do that....and how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to allow more than one row with the same `ID_NO` value?

Comment: @HansUp No...just 1 row per ID_NO

Comment: Choose "Yes (No Duplicates)" for the "Indexed" property of that `ID_NO` field.  In addition to prohibiting more than one row for a given `ID_NO`, that property may also reveal where your code attempts to create duplicate rows.

Comment: Right click `CurrentDb.Execute` and select Go To Definition. We want that function.

Comment: [CurrentDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.currentdb) is a built-in method.  `Execute` is a method of the DAO.Database object reference `CurrentDb` returns.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you open a recordset based on a parameter query which targets the row matching your target `ID_NO` value.

If the recordset is empty at open, you want to add a new row with the `ID_NO` value. Then, whether or not the recordset was empty at open, you can update the values of the remaining fields.

Here is an example for the first 3 fields of your table.  Call it from your "add" and "update" command buttons.

```vb
Private Sub InsertOrUpdate()
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    strSelect = "SELECT ID_NO, DATEIST, INBOUND_FLTS FROM COMM_RRC" & vbCrLf _
        & "WHERE ID_NO = [which_id];"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
    qdf.Parameters("which_id").Value = Me.ID_NO.Value
    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
    If rs.EOF Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs!ID_NO.Value = Me.ID_NO.Value
    Else
        rs.Edit
    End If
    rs!DATEIST.Value = Me.DATEIST.Value
    rs!INBOUND_FLTS.Value = Me.INBOUND_FLTS.Value
    rs.Update
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Command17_Click() you write

```
CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value = ""
```

this means that CODE_SHARE_FLTS is a string. But in Command18_Click() you have no '':

```
CODE_SHARE_FLTS = " & CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value &  " where ID_NO =  '" & ID_NO.Value & " ';"
```

This means that it is a numerical value. Please check what is correct.
For testing it is helpful to execute the SQL statement with

```
docmd.RunSQL
```

This offers more valuable info in case of errors. Later you can change this to

```
CurrentDB.Execute [Your SQL string], dbFailOnError
```

Comment: You are correct the problem must be in quotes also the  CODE_SHARE_FLTS is string but i am not sure what quotes must be used. Could you please correct it for me?

Comment: I have seen this code in an YouTube video and he didnt add ' quote because that value he was trying to fetch was integer. I am new to this and trying to learn....any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Use single quotes like you use it in the other fields.
Additional try to find the problem by first create the SQL statement just for one or a few fields. If this runs without errors add more fields. This way you will find the problematic part of your SQL statement.
Additional you can try to build the SQL statement first in a string variable. This can then easily checked. Later you ca execute it as
CurrentDb.Excute YourStringVariable, dbFailOnError

Comment: Zens suggestion is good approach. Also, be very careful with datatypes in the query: For text fields, use quotes and for numbers no quotes. E.g. the ID_NO.Value should not have quotes. Then for the date expression you could use something like Format(DATEIST.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") to get that updated. The reason for your error can come from using the quotes in wrong place. Then the field names and values can get mixed up and fieldname is not recognized correctly.  Then when query has not found the matching fieldname it interprets it as parameter which you are not giving and therefore the error.

Comment: Thanks Zen I have tried removing single quotes from ID_NO - `  & "',CODE_SHARE_FLTS = '" & CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value & "' where ID_NO =  " & ID_NO.Value & "" ` and while i am trying to update the record its getting updated but once i hit refresh the record copies itself..!! Why is this happening? How can a record get duplicated while updating?

Comment: @MikaOukka Thanks for the help....the DATEIST is getting updated or inserted without any problem but why i am not able to UPDATE...this is really frustrating me as i have spent more than 4 hours trying to fix this...

Comment: And you are not by any change executing the Command16_Click since that would insert a new record based on the field values?

Comment: @MikaOukka insert statement is executing fine....I am just having problem while Updating....

Comment: @randerson The real answer is to use proper parameterization, not **dangerous** SQL injection, and then you wouldn't have to worry about formatting and escaping.

Comment: You are adding a space into your WHERE clause which should not be there: `" where ID_NO =  '" & 
ID_NO.Value & " ';"` should read `" where ID_NO =  '" & ID_NO.Value & "';"`

Comment: @BobS Its giving an error - Run-time error '424': Object required  :(

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should ALWAYS have the statement `Option Explicit` as the first line in each module. This will ensure you have no hidden errors due to misspelled variable names.

Now to your problem. Your issue lies in two areas of the SQL statement. @Zen actually identified both. `ID_NO` is numeric and should not be enclosed in quotes. In addition to that and going back to my previous comment, you are appending a space to `ID_NO.value` in your `WHERE clause` which needs to be removed. You also need to enclose `CODE_SHARE_FLTS.value` in quotes. Your final `UPDATE` statement should read as follows (formatted for readability). You can just copy and paste this into your code:

```
    CurrentDb.Execute "Update COMM_RRC Set " & _
                      "DATEIST = '" & DATEIST.Value & "'," & _
                      "INBOUND_FLTS = '" & INBOUND_FLTS.Value & "'," & _
                      "IB_SECTOR = '" & IB_SECTOR.Value & "'," & _
                      "APT = '" & APT.Value & "'," & _
                      "OUTBOUND_FLTS = '" & OUTBOUND_FLTS.Value & "'," & _
                      "OB_SECTOR = '" & OB_SECTOR.Value & "'," & _
                      "GUESTS = '" & GUESTS.Value & "'," & _
                      "MAX_DIS_TIME = '" & MAX_DIS_TIME.Value & "'," & _
                      "DISP_ACT = '" & DISP_ACT.Value & "'," & _
                      "REMARKS_COMM_RRC = '" & REMARKS_COMM_RRC.Value & "'," & _
                      "NOTE_COMM_RRC = '" & NOTE_COMM_RRC.Value & "'," & _
                      "CODE_SHARE_FLTS = '" & CODE_SHARE_FLTS.Value & "' " & _
                      "Where ID_NO = " & ID_NO.Value & ";", dbFailOnError
```

@MikaOukka also pointed out a potential issue with DATEIST which you should address. If you leave it as is then there is a potential for it to come back and bite you in future.